# How to delete a key that I just generated?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, key

I have a 2 node hadoop cluster.

I ran this command on the master:

```
$ssh-copy-id -i /home/hadoop/.ssh/id_rsa.pub hadoop@192.168.1.1
```

**How can I undo this?** I would actually like to reassign the key.

`192.168.1.1` is the slave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing like **undo** in Linux as such. You have a couple of options though,

**Option 1 :** Go to the slave machine, press CTRL+H(to reveal the hidden files and folders). Move to the .ssh folder, open `authorized_keys` file and delete the key.

**Option 2 :** If you do not have direct access to slave machine, ssh to it and try this :

1- Make a copy of the authorized_keys file so that you don't loose other keys

```
cp ~/.ssh/authorized_keys ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2
```

2- Open ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2 file and mark the line where your last key starts and then do this :

> head -n -3 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2 > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
>
> (Assuming that last 3 lines of ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2 are the key you had added last)

HTH

Answer (score 1):

uthorized keys are (usually) stored in the respective users home directory in the subfolder `.ssh` in a file `authorized keys`. it is one key per line and you can edit the file with any text editor and just delete the respective line.